# Большая погрешность при разложении функции на степенной ряд

Tags: java, ряды

Для х изменяющегося от a до b с шагом (b-a)/k, где (k=10), вычислить функцию f(x), используя ее разложение в степенной ряд в трех случаях:

- а) для заданного n;
- б) для заданной точности e (e=0.0001);
- с) для    «точного» значения (по аналитической формуле).

Для сравнения найти относительную погрешность вычисления функции значение функции о_погр = ABS( (точ_знач – приближ_знач)/ точ_знач)

- функция: y=-ln|2sinx/2|
- диапазон изменения аргумента: pi/5<=x<=9pi/5
- n=40
- сумма: S=cosx+cos2x/2+...+cosnx/n

  ```
    package laboratornaya3; 
  import static java.lang.Math.*; 
  public class Laboratornaya3 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
  double a = PI / 5, 
  b = 9 * PI / 5, 
  E = 0.0001, 
  pSN, pSE; 
  int n = 40; 
  double dx=(b-a)/10; 
  //Шапка 
  System.out.printf("%-15s %-30s %-30s %-30s %-30s %-30s", "x", "y", "SN", "SE", "pSN", "pSE"); 
  System.out.println(); 
  for (double x = a; x <= b; x += dx) 
  { 
  // Точное значение Y 
  double y = -log(abs(2*sin(x/2))); 
  // SN 
  double SN = 0; 
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
  { 
  SN += cos(i*x)/i; 
  } 
  // SE 
  double SE = 0; 
  int i = 1; 
  double step; 
  do 
  { 
  step = cos(i*x)/i; 
  SE+=step; 
  i++; 
  } 
  while (abs(step)>E); 
  // погрешности 
  pSN = abs((y - SN) / y); 
  pSE = abs((y - SE) / y); 
  //вывод 
  System.out.printf("%-15s %-30s %-30s %-30s %-30s %-30s", 
  String.format("%.5f", x), y, SN, SE, pSN, pSE); 
  System.out.println(); 
  } 
  } 
  }
  ```

Comment: что тут вам нужно? погрешность увеличить?

Comment: нет, наоборот, уменьшить

Comment: Большая погрешность при вычислениях с n(pSN) не очень волнует, а вот вычисление с заданной точностью(pSE) вызывает вопросы. Задала наблюдение за шагом(step) и он почему-то моментами увеличивается как будто не успевает досчитать в заданном диапазоне, поэтому думаю, что ошибка в условии выхода из while, но какое тогда задать условие? C математикой, к сожалению, средненько, поэтому, возможно, что-то я не так понимаю в разложении функции в степенной ряд